# how can read .csv file in google colab?

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I try to read the dataset in CSV format in google colab. when I ran this code, it took a lot of time and it hasn't stopped running yet to show the result of running the code. How can I fix it? Thank you for your consideration. here is my code in python.

```
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
with open('dataset.csv', 'r') as data:
    df3 = pd.read_csv('data', encoding = ('ansi'))
    print (df3)
```

here is the link of dataset:
[enter link description here](http://gitlab.rahnemacollege.com/rahnemacollege/tuning-registration-JusticeInWork/raw/master/dataset.csv)

Comment: Why there is quote around data in `pd.read_csv`. Use : `df3 = pd.read_csv(data, encoding = ('ansi'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the quotes,because there it is a variable which holds the value as dataset.csv so you don't need to mention quotes there.

Answer (score 3):

`data` is a variable, you need to use it as such

```
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
with open('dataset.csv', 'r') as data:
    df3 = pd.read_csv(data, encoding = ('ansi'))
    print (df3)
```